Npm package whatsapp-web.js broke
I have been working with whatsapp-wb.js for a while. Recently the package is not working anymore.
Firstly, when I try their latest package i.e. "whatsapp-web.js": "^1.23.0", even before the qr code shows up, it throws:
.../node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/webCache/LocalWebCache.js:34
        const version = indexHtml.match(/manifest-([\d\\.]+)\.json/)[1];
                                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')

On manually adding "?." to fix this, the qrcode shows up. Then after scanning, it throws:
.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:221
            throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                  ^

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:5:95
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async Client.initialize (.../node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/Client.js:323:9)

Tried the following solutions:

Removed the package and reinstalled it.
Made a sample fresh node project and still same errors.
Whatsapp-web js doesn't fire ready event
https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/1786
On trying some older versions (such as whatsapp-web.js@1.16.4-alpha.0) after changing the selector to INTRO_IMG_SELECTOR = '[data-icon='search'], it throws:

.../node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:221
            throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                  ^

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at fillModuleArray (eval at <anonymous> (:2:5), <anonymous>:6:74)
    at moduleRaid (eval at <anonymous> (:2:5), <anonymous>:15:3)
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:4:17
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (.../node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (.../node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async Client.initialize (.../node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/Client.js:322:9)

Any ideas how to get it working again?

Ask on Discord or open an issue on GitHub

Raise an issue at the corresponding repository.

This fix worked:
https://discord.com/channels/698610475432411196/698610475931271249/1224646302609047552
Thanks guys and discord community!

Sorry @AhmedNaeem but the link you mentioned does not contain any type of information, I arrived at an empty channel... It would be very useful if you edited the post and commented on the solution you found

Add this argument to your Client initialization:
webVersionCache: {
    type: 'remote',
    remotePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.2412.54.html',
    }

It should end up looking like this:
const client = new Client({
  webVersionCache: {
    type: "remote",
    remotePath:
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.2412.54.html",
  },
});


Thank you so much. I was in a hackathon and the bot stopped working with 2 hours left. this helped!
